# AWS API Gateway: 403 Forbidden response to preflight OPTIONS request

Tags: node.js, reactjs, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, fetch-api

I am on my way to creating an API using AWS API Gateway. I have created a PUT method to perform some functionality on my database.

You can see in the image below, I have set the following as my response headers on AWS.

[image]

This is how I am making my request to React JS:

```
fetch('https://myawsurl.execute-api.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/Dev/search', {
  method: 'PUT',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type':'application/json',
    'Access-Control-Request-Method': 'PUT',
    'Access-Control-Request-Headers': 'Content-Type'
  },
  body: {
   "searchby": JSON.stringify({"searchby":"test"}),
  }
 }).then(res=>res.json()).
 then((data)=>this.setState({
  jobs:data,
  isLoading:false,
 }));
```

Whenever I invoke the fetch, I get the following error on my chrome console:

'*Access to fetch at 'https://myawsurl.execute-api.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/Dev/search' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.*'

[image]

From what I see I have clearly got the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' on my response.

I know postman works differently, but I don't any get error while making the same request on the postman.

Here is a screenshot of what response header for the same request made via postman

[image]

Strangely, The error on firefox is differently than to that of the chrome.

[image]

Comment: The screenshot shows that the response is a 403 error. That’s the problem that needs be fixed. The Access-Control-\* response headers you set just don’t get added to 4xx errors. You need to configure the server to respond to OPTIONS request with a 200 OK rather that a 403 error. If you do that, the headers you set will get added to the response as expected.

Comment: I needed to play around for a but it works now. I added an OPTIONS resource on my AWS API gateway with necessary response headers. I also changed the way my request body is structured, apparently, I wasn't sending the JSON data correctly.

Comment: Glad to hear you got it working

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you already have your answer but for others browsing this post the reason for the failure is that the [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) headers were not returned by the [OPTIONS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/OPTIONS) method.

The browser calls this method on our behalf before calling the PUT method. This is expected behavior.

Here is api gateway's documentation on CORS

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-cors.html